# Autofill article number by using production number

Tags: excel

I am working on automating a report.

As a part of this report the user has to fill in article number and production number, even though theese two are knitted together. Which means that in some other excel file there are two columns, one for production numbers and one for article numbers, hence my thought is that if you know one of them, you could automatically copy the other...

I was thinking I could paste theese two columns in sheet2 of a standard report..

**My question**: Does anybody have any sugestions of how to do this with as little coding as possible, maybe even just excel functions?

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Comment: Thanks pnuts, I was suspecting there already existed some formulas for this, and vlookup worked like a charm!

And Jean-Francois, I never asked for a complete solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, as pnuts commented, that VLOOKUP solves this problem.
There even exists a guide on how to make the function work:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13780/using-vlookup-in-excel/